# ST_WITHIN function does not exist

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

Im confused on how to use this function within my query. My code that I am using is as follows:

```
$res = pg_query($conn, 'SELECT "Coordinates" FROM "Shapes" WHERE st_within(point(0,0)::geometry, "Coordinates") ');
```

When I try run this I get this error:

**Warning**: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: function st_within(geometry, geography) does not exist

HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I want Coordinates to a polygon, so this may need to be an array of geometries

Comment: The [`ST_Within` documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html) says both arguments are geometry, does "Coordinates" count?

Comment: So Coordinates is a geography but I want this to be a polygon, so an array of geometries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and tried some different functions, with this I got different errors, one appeared as such:

**Warning**: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: contains: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (Polygon, 4326) !=
(Point, 0) in **/var/www/html/watchlist/coordChange.php** on line **45**

Using the following code:

```
pg_query($conn, 'SELECT "Coordinates" FROM "Shapes" WHERE st_within( ST_MakePoint(130, -25), "Coordinates"::geometry) ');
```

From here I searched some more and used another function ST_SetSRID(), like so:

```
pg_query($conn, 'SELECT "Coordinates" FROM "Shapes" WHERE st_within( ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(130, -25), 4326), "Coordinates"::geometry) ');
```

This then produced the result I want.

Comment: You can change cast operation like this "::geometry(GEOMETRY,4326)"

Comment: You may use [ST_Intersects](https://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) or [ST_Covers](https://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Covers.html) without geography to  geometry type casting. See [PostGIS Geography Support Functions](https://www.postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_GeographyFunctions)

Answer (score 1):

ST_Within function takes two geometry parameters like this "ST_Within(geometry A, geometry B)". You should make sure the parameters of "Coordinates" is actually geometry.

Comment: Coordinates is a geography so Id have to convert this correct?

Comment: yeah, Postgis document says "Returns TRUE if geometry A is completely inside geometry B." for ST_Within function. geography and geometry  is not the same type of data so you have to change parameter of "Coordinates"  from geography  to geometry.